# Is there a Raspberry Pi emulator?

Tags: emulation, bare-metal

For doing bare metal programming, it would be really useful if there was a software emulator for the Raspberry Pi which I could use for debugging and inspection of state. Does such a thing exist?

I've seen some people using qemu with a custom kernel to run Raspbian on the versatilepb platform. But that's not the same thing, because that's not emulating the Raspberry Pi hardware --- it's merely emulating a similar but different ARM board. I need something which actually thinks it's a Pi.

Comment: I'm guessing the *no* here has to do with the proprietary nature of the hardware.   The only people who could create such an emulator would be Broadcom, and they aren't going to do that.  However, the processor is an implementation of a broader standard (ARM 1176), so to the extent that this is not good enough for your purposes you might want to step back and consider the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378).  If there's no more to it than what you've said here, there is no X therefore you can discard Y.

Comment: What sort of software programming? Apart from the GPIO and the GPU etc implementation, you should be able to simulate it close enough for some programming.

Comment: It's all the fiddly bootup stuff, setting up the page tables, configuring devices, making sure the UART is hooked up to interrupts properly, etc. I.e. all the platform-specific stuff which emulating another platform won't help with.

Comment: I find it hard to believe *the page tables* aren't part of the ISA...but then I don't have much of a hat to eat here.

Comment: You might wanna go through this thread. https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=72&t=26561 Torlus' qemu branch allows you to emulate Raspi platform without any modification in kernel or rootfs. I was having trouble while running the latest images and kernel with it, but it works fine with older wheezy images and suitable kernel. If you want to go deeper, this could be the first step. Happy hacking. :)

Comment: The chances of someone developing an emulator at the cost of 100s of thousands of pounds for a £15 device seem a bit slim.

Comment: ...except, of course, it seems that somebody has... @dastaan: that looks like it's precisely what I'm looking for. I haven't had a chance to actually try it yet, but could you write that up as an answer? Then I can comment on whether it actually works or not.

Comment: One that @flakeshake mentioned in his answer seems to be in active development. Even I wasn't aware of it. Good to know. On the other hand, torlus' branch is not under active development.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

QEMU supports a platform called "raspi2" directly since version 2.6 at least. I believe work is ongoing to refine
the support for all Pi models including the RPi3. Currently , only older Raspbian images and Windows IoT Core  are *partially* supported.

http://wiki.qemu.org/ChangeLog/2.6

Comment: I've tried this out and it works fine --- it's already been invaluable for developing my test program. It seems to support both the Pi and the Pi 2, although figuring out which you have is a bit hard because it doesn't appear to support ATAGS on boot, but I can work round that easily enough. Thanks very much!

Comment: Very nice... Is there also a download that is already compiled?

Comment: Think I found a compiled one, at least for earlier models: https://sourceforge.net/projects/rpiqemuwindows/?source=typ_redirect